# Unmarshal single-item JSON list to single nested struct

Tags: json, go

I have JSON coming from a graph database and it only returns lists. Here is an example query and response:

```
{
  Course(func: eq(XID, "1")) {
    Name
      Holes : Hole {
        Number
        Tee {
          Color
          Basket @facets(distance) {
            Designation 
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

This query looks up by ID so it can only return one result but the nature of the database backend means it will always return a list like so:

```
{
  "Course": [
    {
      "Name": "NAD",
      "Holes": [
        {
          "Number": 1,
          "Tee": [
            {
              "Color": "Blue",
              "Basket": [
                {
                  "Designation": "A",
                  "Basket|distance": "70"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "Color": "Red",
              "Basket": [
                {
                  "Designation": "A",
                  "Basket|distance": "69"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Number": 2,
          "Tee": [
            {
              "Color": "Blue",
              "Basket": [
                {
                  "Designation": "A",
                  "Basket|distance": "79"
                },
                {
                  "Designation": "B",
                  "Basket|distance": "89"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "Color": "Red",
              "Basket": [
                {
                  "Designation": "A",
                  "Basket|distance": "79"
                },
                {
                  "Designation": "B",
                  "Basket|distance": "95"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to unmarshal that single Course to a struct:

```
type Course struct {
    Name  string `json:"Name"`
    Holes []struct {
        Number int `json:"Number"`
        Tee    []struct {
            Color  string `json:"Color"`
            Basket []struct {
                Designation    string `json:"Designation"`
                BasketDistance string `json:"Basket|distance"`
            } `json:"Basket"`
        } `json:"Tee"`
    } `json:"Holes"`
}
```

I tried making a temporary struct that is just a list of courses to pull out the correct JSON by index but I get a really generic runtime error that the object can't be unmarshaled to that type.

I believe it would be relatively easy to convert it to a `[]map[string]interface{}` then unmarshal to a Course from there by specifying the JSONRawMessage type but doesn't that suffer a performance penalty? What's the most performant way to solve this problem?

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/xxCm2kIcprB

Comment: Maybe less fast than manually writing your own parser for your specific use case and going byte-by-byte, but probably faster than using the standard library: check out https://github.com/tidwall/gjson

Comment: You should provide the *"generic runtime"* error together with the temporary struct and the unmarshaling code if you seek help.

Comment: @mkopriva Thank you! I think my problem when I tried to implement this myself was I was trying to unmarshal twice because I was expecting to have to deal with the raw JSON list then a list of JSONRawMessage types.